# How to improve performance of multi field search in MongoDB?

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I have a collection (~900k of docs and counting). The doc scheme you can see in attachment. I want to search by almost every field in any sub document in any field combination. For example:

```
# search 1
updated_at > now() and make.id = 10 and model.id = 20

# search 2
region.id = 10 and details.year >= 2000 and details.body = 'sedan'
```

**Hardware:** 4 x Intel Xeon E5-2650 at 2.60GHz, 16 gb RAM, SSD disk, 8gb swap on SDD drive.
**App dependencies:** python 3.6, Django, mongoengine, pymongo.

Here more info:
[Sample document](https://gist.github.com/alex-oleshkevich/1c72836f8ef33fc36a9ce885635372b5), 
[Indices setup](https://gist.github.com/alex-oleshkevich/67370b0d4d278c152ab9e687f1e2c06b),
[Database and server status](https://gist.github.com/alex-oleshkevich/0ae57b8f3e72ea24cac341c570397273)

Comment: not much, various index combos, aggragations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I ended with elasticsearch + mongo-connector.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider a data model that would be more efficient for this type of access pattern.

Performance in MongoDB is achieved by making sure your queries are fully indexed, and that the indexes being used can [fit in memory (or in cache, for WiredTiger)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/). Access patterns that would allow for querying on any combination of a number of fields will be expensive, as it will inevitably lead to trying to index every combination of fields, which would be fighting a losing battle.

Consider a [faceted search data model](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/faceted-search-with-mongodb), which would allow for a limited set of indexes to better cover a wide range of query filters.